# How can I turn shaders off and on at specific points in my Three JS scene?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating a THREEjs animation which I eventually want to sync with audio. (Can't accomplish this currently) I would like to add and remove shaders at specific points. How can I accomplish this most efficiently?

The way I have it set up now, is that I have a mirror shader inside of a function called `turnOnMirror` and in my render function, I have a conditional statement,

```
if (audioSrc.context.currentTime > 32.0) { turnOnMirror(); }
```

The shader looks like this:

```
var mirror = mirrorPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.MirrorShader );
    mirror.renderToScreen = true;
    composer.addPass(mirror);
```

(I am doing this for 2 reasons!

A: The renderer is the only place I can grab the actual time to make this call. And B: because for whatever reason, my `frequencyData` array comes back as 0s.

However, when the scene reaches this point, everything slows down extremely. How can I keep the same frame rate and accomplish what I am attempting to at the same time?

A piece of information for you is that the scene works fine at the same constant speed if I just apply the shader without making the call in the render function.

You can view the site [here](http://jshuadvd.com)!

And the source code for the `main.js` is below!

```
/* ==================== [ Global Variables ] ==================== */

var scene, camera, renderer, aspectRatio;
var stats;
var composer, effect, clock;
var backMesh;


/* ==================== [ Audio Context ] ==================== */

var ctx = new AudioContext();
var audio = document.getElementById('player');

audio.play();
audio.volume = 1;
// audio.crossOrigin = "anonymous";

var audioSrc = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
var analyser = ctx.createAnalyser();

audioSrc.connect(analyser);
audioSrc.connect(ctx.destination);


// frequencyBinCount tells you how many values you'll receive from the analyser
var frequencyData = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getByteFrequencyData(frequencyData);

console.log(audioSrc);
console.log(audioSrc.context.currentTime);
console.log(frequencyData);


console.log(analyser.fftSize); // 2048 by default
console.log(analyser.frequencyBinCount); // will give us 1024 data points

analyser.fftSize = 64;
console.log(analyser.frequencyBinCount); // fftSize/2 = 32 data points


/* ==================== [ Set Scene & Camera ] ==================== */

scene = new THREE.Scene();
// scene.fog = new THREE.Fog(0x000000, 0, 1200);
aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 100);
// camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 10, 10, 10 );

// Set the DOM
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor("#000000");
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

/* ==================== [ Camera Position ] ==================== */

camera.position.z = 15;
camera.position.y = 0;

/* ==================== [ Point Lights ] ==================== */

var pointLightBlue = new THREE.PointLight("#00ccff", 5, 100, 2);
pointLightBlue.position.set(-10, -40, -10);
scene.add(pointLightBlue);

// var pointLightWhite = new THREE.PointLight( "#ffffff", 1, 0, 1 );
// // pointLightWhite.position.set( -10, 160, -10 );
// pointLightWhite.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
// scene.add(pointLightWhite);
// camera.add(pointLightWhite);

// var pointLightPink = new THREE.PointLight( "#EE567C", 5, 100, 10 );
// pointLightPink.position.set( 1, 0, -5 );
// scene.add(pointLightPink);

var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight("#A805FA", 2, 100, 40);
pointLight.position.set(40, 0, 40);
scene.add(pointLight);

var light2 = new THREE.PointLight( 0xFFFFFF, 1, 100 );
scene.add( light2 );
light2.position.z = 1000;

var pointLight2 = new THREE.PointLight("#07FAA0", 2, 100, 30);
pointLight2.position.set(-40, 0, -40);
scene.add(pointLight2);

/* ==================== [ Particles ] ==================== */

var getCamera = function() {
    return camera;
}

// var texture = new Image();
// texture.src = 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82015/snowflake.png';
// texture.src = './images/particle.png';
//var material = new THREE.ParticleBasicMaterial( { map: new THREE.Texture(texture) } );

var particleCount = 0, particleSystem, particles;
THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('./images/particle.png');
//console.log(texture);


particleCount = 20000,
particles = new THREE.Geometry();
var pMaterial = new THREE.PointCloudMaterial({
  color: 0xFFFFFF,
    map: texture,
    blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending,
    depthTest: false,
    depthWrite: false,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.3,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  size: 1.2
});

for (var i = 0; i < particleCount; i++) {
    var pX = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
        pY = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
        pZ = Math.random() * 500 - 250,
        particle = new THREE.Vector3(pX, pY, pZ);

    particles.vertices.push(particle);
}

particleSystem = new THREE.ParticleSystem(particles, pMaterial);
particleSystem.sortParticles = false;
particleSystem.frustumCulled = false;
scene.add(particleSystem);


/* ==================== [ Light Beams ] ==================== */

var BEAM_ROT_SPEED = 0.003;
var BEAM_COUNT = 360;
var beamGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(1, 500, 10, 1);
beamGroup = new THREE.Object3D();
beamMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    opacity: 0.02,
    transparent: true,
});

for (var i = 0; i <= BEAM_COUNT; ++i) {
    var beam = new THREE.Mesh(beamGeometry, beamMaterial);
    beam.doubleSided = true;
    beam.rotation.x = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    beam.rotation.y = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    beam.rotation.z = Math.random() * Math.PI;
    beamGroup.add(beam);
}
scene.add(beamGroup);
beamGroup.translateZ( -5 );

/* ==================== [ Cubes ] ==================== */

var doStrobe = false;
var doShake = false;
var strobeOn = false;
var beatTime = 30;

THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
var imgTextureStripes2 = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "./images/stripes2.jpg" );
imgTextureStripes2.wrapS = imgTextureStripes2.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
imgTextureStripes2.repeat.set( 100, 100 );
backMaterial2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    map:imgTextureStripes2
} );

backMesh2 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1900, 30, 20 ), backMaterial2  );
backMesh2.scale.x = -1;
scene.add( backMesh2 );
backMesh2.visible = false;


function Box() {
    this.posn = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.rotation = new THREE.Vector3();
    this.speed = getRand(3, 20);
    this.init();
}

Box.ORIGIN = new THREE.Vector3();
Box.MAX_DISTANCE = 1000;
Box.INIT_POSN_RANGE = 500;
Box.FRONT_PLANE_Z = 1000;
Box.BACK_PLANE_Z = -1000;

Box.prototype.init = function() {
    this.posn.copy(Box.ORIGIN);
    this.posn.x = getRand(-Box.INIT_POSN_RANGE,Box.INIT_POSN_RANGE);
    this.posn.y = getRand(-Box.INIT_POSN_RANGE,Box.INIT_POSN_RANGE);
    this.posn.z = Box.BACK_PLANE_Z;
    this.rotation.x = (Math.random() * 360 ) * Math.PI / 180;
    this.rotation.y = (Math.random() * 360 ) * Math.PI / 180;
    this.rotation.z = (Math.random() * 360 ) * Math.PI / 180;
};

Box.prototype.update = function() {
    this.posn.z += this.speed * sketchParams.cubeSpeed ;
    this.rotation.x += 0.03;
    this.rotation.y += 0.01;

    if(this.posn.z > Box.FRONT_PLANE_Z) {
        this.init();
    }
};

// returns random number within a range
function getRand(minVal, maxVal) {
    return minVal + (Math.random() * (maxVal - minVal));
}

var cubesize = 100;
var BOX_COUNT;
var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(cubesize, cubesize, cubesize);
cubeHolder = new THREE.Object3D();

THREE.ImageUtils.crossOrigin = '';
imgTextureStripes = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "./images/stripes2.jpg" );
cubeMaterial  = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
    ambient: 0x111111,
    color: 0x666666,
    specular: 0x999999,
    shininess: 30,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    map:imgTextureStripes
});

for(i = 0; i < BOX_COUNT; i++) {
    var box = new Box();
    console.log(box);
    boxes.push(box);
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry,cubeMaterial );
    cube.position = box.posn;
    cube.rotation = box.rotation;
    cube.ox = cube.scale.x = Math.random() * 1 + 1;
    cube.oy = cube.scale.y = Math.random() * 1 + 1;
    cube.oz = cube.scale.z = Math.random() * 1 + 1;
    cubeHolder.add(cube);
}
scene.add(cubeHolder);

/* ==================== [ Mini Geometries ] ==================== */



/* ==================== [ Post Processing ] ==================== */

composer = new THREE.EffectComposer(renderer);
composer.addPass(new THREE.RenderPass(scene, camera));

effect = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.FilmShader);
effect.uniforms['time'].value = 2.0;
effect.uniforms['nIntensity'].value = 0.4;
effect.uniforms['sIntensity'].value = 0.9;
effect.uniforms['sCount'].value = 1800;
effect.uniforms['grayscale'].value = 0.8;
composer.addPass(effect);

// var dot = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.DotScreenShader );
// dot.uniforms[ 'scale' ].value = 400;
// dot.uniforms[ 'tDiffuse' ].value = 40;
// dot.uniforms[ 'tSize' ].value = new THREE.Vector2( 256, 256 );
// composer.addPass(dot);

// var kaleidoPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.KaleidoShader);
// kaleidoPass.uniforms['sides'].value = 3;
// kaleidoPass.uniforms['angle'].value = 45 * Math.PI / 180;
// composer.addPass(kaleidoPass);

// var mirror = mirrorPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.MirrorShader );
// // mirror.uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = 1.0;
// // mirror.uniforms[ "side" ].value = 3;
// composer.addPass(mirror);

var glitch = new THREE.GlitchPass(64);
glitch.uniforms[ "tDiffuse" ].value = 1.0;
glitch.uniforms[ 'seed' ].value = Math.random() * 5;
glitch.uniforms[ 'byp' ].value = 0;
// glitch.goWild = true;
composer.addPass(glitch);

var superPass = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.SuperShader);
superPass.uniforms.vigDarkness.value = 1;
superPass.uniforms.vigOffset.value =  1.3;
superPass.uniforms.glowSize.value = 2;
superPass.uniforms.glowAmount.value = 1;
composer.addPass( superPass );

var tv = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.BadTVShader );
tv.uniforms[ "distortion" ].value = 1;
tv.uniforms[ "distortion2" ].value = .01;
// tv.uniforms[ "time" ].value = 1.5;
tv.uniforms[ "speed" ].value = 8.8;
tv.uniforms[ "rollSpeed" ].value = 0.8;
composer.addPass(tv);

var staticPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.StaticShader );
staticPass.uniforms[ "amount" ].value = 0.15;
staticPass.uniforms[ "size" ].value = 1.0;
staticPass.uniforms[ "time" ].value = 4.5;
composer.addPass(staticPass);

var effect1 = new THREE.ShaderPass(THREE.RGBShiftShader);
effect1.uniforms['amount'].value = 0.003;
effect1.renderToScreen = true;
composer.addPass(effect1);


function turnOnMirror() {

    var mirror = mirrorPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.MirrorShader );
    mirror.renderToScreen = true;
    composer.addPass(mirror);
}

function turnOffMirror() {
    var mirror = mirrorPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.MirrorShader );
    mirror.renderToScreen = false;
    composer.addPass(mirror);
}

// add a timer
clock = new THREE.Clock;

/* ==================== [ Stats ] ==================== */

// stats = new Stats();
// stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
// stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
// stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
// document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
// document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

/* ==================== [ Shapes ] ==================== */

var quantity = 40;
var shapes = [];

for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {

    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
        var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry(4, 40, 3);
        // geometry.position = 0;

        // var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 30, 30, 18);
        // camera.position.z = 60;

        // var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 20, 150, 18);

        // var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 20, 150, 18);

        // var geometry = new THREE.TorusKnotGeometry( 10, 3, 100, 16 );
    }

    else {

      //var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 4, 40, 3);

        // var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 30, 30, 18);

        // var geometry = new THREE.RingGeometry( 1, 5, 6 );
        // var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00,
        //   side: THREE.DoubleSide } );
        // var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        // scene.add( mesh );
    }

    if (i % 7 === 0) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: "#ffffff"
        });
    } else if (i % 2 === 0) {
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: "#666666"
        });
    } else {
        var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            color: "#333333"
        });
    }

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.position.z = -i * 3;
    // mesh.rotation.z = i;
    shapes.push(mesh);
    scene.add(mesh);
}

// function refRate() {
//   curTime = Date.now();
//   delta = curTime - oldTime;
//
//   if (delta > interval) {
//     oldTime = curTime - (delta % interval);
//     updateSize();
//   }
//
// }

// Variables
var u_time = 0;

/* ==================== [ Render Function ] ==================== */

var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    // var timer = Date.now() * 0.0010;
    // camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    u_time++;

    for (var i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {

        // Set rotation change of shapes
        shapes[i].position.z += 0.2;
        shapes[i].rotation.z += 0;
        shapes[i].scale.x = 1 + Math.sin(i + u_time * 0.1) * 0.05;
        shapes[i].scale.y = 1 + Math.sin(i + u_time * 0.1) * 0.05;
        // shapes[i].scale.y = 120 + Math.tan(i + u_time * 5.0) * 0.5;
        // shapes[i].scale.x = 120 + Math.tan(i + u_time * 5.0) * 0.5;

        var change = 1.5 + Math.sin(u_time * 0.5) * 0.5;

        // Set wireframe & width
        if (Math.random() < change) {
            shapes[i].material.wireframe = false;
            shapes[i].material.wireframeLinewidth = Math.random() * 2;
            // if (shapes[i] / 2 === 0) {
            //  turnOnMirror();
            // }
        }
        else {
            shapes[i].material.wireframe = false;
        }

        if (shapes[i].position.z > 10) {
            shapes[i].position.z = -70;
            shapes[i].rotation.z = i;
        }
    }

    // Set Point light Intensity & Position
    pointLight.intensity = Math.abs(Math.sin(u_time * 0.2) * 2);
    pointLight2.intensity = Math.abs(Math.cos(u_time * 0.2) * 2);
    pointLight.position.z = Math.abs(Math.sin(u_time * 0.02) * 30);
    pointLight2.position.z = Math.abs(Math.cos(u_time * 0.02) * 30);


    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  composer.render();

    var pCount = particleCount;
      while (pCount--) {
            var camz = getCamera().position.z;
      var particle = particles.vertices[pCount];
      particle.y = Math.random() * 500 - 250;
            //particleSystem.vertices[i].z = camz  +  Math.random()*600 + 200 ;
      particleSystem.geometry.vertices.needsUpdate = true;
      }

      particleSystem.rotation.y += -0.001;
      particleSystem.rotation.z += 0.005;

        var normLevel = 0.2;
        beamGroup.rotation.x += BEAM_ROT_SPEED;
        beamGroup.rotation.y += BEAM_ROT_SPEED;
        beamMaterial.opacity = Math.min(normLevel * 0.4, 0.6);
        camera.rotation.z += 0.003;

        if (doShake) {
        var maxshake = 60;

        var shake = normLevel * maxshake ;
        camera.position.x = Math.random()*shake - shake/2;
        camera.position.y = Math.random()*shake - shake/2;
        }

    camera.rotation.z += 0.003;
    // camera.rotation.y += 0.005;
    // camera.rotation.x -= 0.003;
    //camera.rotation.z += 0.03;

    if (doStrobe){
    strobeOn = !strobeOn;
        if (strobeOn){
            light2.intensity = 2;
        }
        else {
            light2.intensity = 0.5;
        }
    }
    else {
        light2.intensity = 0.2;
    }

    // flash background on level threshold
    if (normLevel > 0.5 ){
        renderer.setClearColor ( 0xFFFFFF );
        backMesh2.visible = true;
    }
    else{
        renderer.setClearColor ( 0x000000 );
        backMesh2.visible = false;
    }

    // show stripes for 6 frames on beat
    backMesh2.visible = beatTime < 6;

    for(var i = 0; i < BOX_COUNT; i++) {
    boxes[i].update();
  }

    if (audioSrc.context.currentTime > 32) {
        turnOnMirror();
    }

    // console.log(audioSrc.context.currentTime);

}

render();
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what "turn off shader" means and what you expect to accomplish. If you don't want something to render either take it out of the scene or mark it as `someObj.visible = false`. If you want to change a shader the set the object's material to some other material. For shader passes it looks like `pass.enabled = false` will work

Comment: Thank you. If you look in the render function, almost the last line `if (audioSrc.context.currentTime > 32) { turnOnMirror();  }`. The `turnOnMirror()` function simply adds this `var mirror = mirrorPass = new THREE.ShaderPass( THREE.MirrorShader );
    mirror.renderToScreen = true;
    composer.addPass(mirror);` shader material to the whole scene at the point when the `audioSrc.context.currentTime > 32.0` however, the scene drops from 30fps to 1fps when this is active in the render function. If I move it out to make the call elsewhere, `audioSrc.context.currentTime` doesn't update.

Comment: `turnOnMirror` is calling `addPass`. That means every time you call it you'r adding yet more passes. Just add the passes once at init time and turn them on and off with `mirrorPass.enabled = false/true`?

Comment: @gman this works, Thank you! I have updated the link http://jshuadvd.com to reflect the changes. I am still having slight performance issues when it gets to that section in making the true/false call. Any ideas on how to keep a constant frame rate of 60fps? Please add this as an answer and I will mark it answered. :)

Comment: @jshuadvd Hello, I stumbled across your post. I went to your site and checked the console. It appears you are still having your audio frequency  array be full of 0's. I just recently have gone into syncing audio with three.js and am having no problems with that. If you are still working on this and would like to discuss please reach out. Thank you.

Comment: @gman thanks for the info on enabling and disabling shader passes. I've been looking for this exact thing! I had believed it was .renderToScreen = disabled/enabled but I was misinformed. Thank you